# Create filtered drop down list based on value

Tags: excel, vlookup

Looking to create a filtered drop down list based on a value.

Ex. [image]

I would want to get only the Name column values where the Group column equals 'CURRENCY' into a dynamic drop down list. More values would be added so the source data would be dynamic as well. I've tried vlookup but would need to look backwards to get the name values which wasn't working out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your `Excel` Version? are you using `O365` ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I'm using Office 365

Comment: And will it be possible for you to show, how your output will be, are you actually looking for a dynamic data validation or you just need the `COLUMN A` Values based on `CURRENCY`? That will be helpful since I have already created the solution just want to confirm check from your end, if not asking too much!

Comment: It would be the latter. Column A values based on 'CURRENCY' into a dynamic validation for a drop down field on a different cell. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer in answers, I have shared, also refer the working file --> `CURRENCY`, I have attached !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets assume, you have the database from cell A1 till C4, and need a dynamic dropdown in cell **F2** based on **Column C** value **CURRENCY**

• First create a helper column in Cell **H2** and enter the below formula

```
=FILTER(A:A,C:C="CURRENCY")
```

• Now select the cell **F2**, and from **Data Tab**, click **Data Validation**

• Under **Settings** Tab --> **Validation Criteria** --> **Allow** --> Select --> **List**

• Enter below formula in **Source** -->

```
=$H2#
```

• Press **OK**.

Now whenever you add new data to the original source the data validation list shall show the required **Names** based on the specific criteria i.e. **[CURRENCY](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cg0yzFJp177gvCA5z?e=WbpbkB)**!

[image: DYNAMIC_DROPDOWN]